# Display the result of JavaScript function on the second HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages. In one of them, we have the JavaScript functions code. In the other one, we want to show the result of the function.

First HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function penAcBoyut(adres, genislik, yukseklik)
{
    var param = "width=" + genislik + "," + "height=" + yukseklik;
    window.open(adres, "_blank", param);
}

function penAcBoyutTest()
{
    penAcBoyut("buton2.html", 400, 300);
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="penAcBoyutTest()">Click me</button>
```

Second HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function penAcBoyutTest() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

When you click the button on the first page, that open the new page. But the counter doesn't work, doesn't increase the clicks label.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only get to second page using first page, then execute the function on page load event of second page.

Can use localStorage(preferably) or cookies to store data if needed to pass on.

EDIT:
using localStorage:

to set a value.

```
if(window.localStorage)

    localStorage.setItem('a',1);
```

and to retrieve:

```
if(window.localStorage)

  var a =localStorage.getItem('a');
```

Comment: Could you send me some examples about that. I look for it on google but actually i don't understand how to use it.